# cannot build cpr library from vcpkg

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, vcpkg

Hello i'm fairy new to C++ i've been trying to use cpr , i've installed it with vcpkg

here is my cmakelists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET x64-mingw-dynamic)
include(path/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)


add_executable(Scrapy main.cpp)

find_package(cpr CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cpr::cpr )
```

and here is my main.cpp

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
int main(int, char**) {

cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://docs.libcpr.org/"});
r.status_code;                  
r.header["content-type"];       
r.text;
printf("it works" );               
return 0;

}
```

now when i try and lunch main.cpp
this what i get in the output

```
cpr::Session::Session():
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:71: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)


[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:160: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::substr(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:191: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::reserve(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::Session::SetSslOptions(cpr::SslOptions const&)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:488: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator[](unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::Session::GetDownloadFileLength()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:647: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find(char, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/session.cpp:647: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::substr(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `_M_create<cpr::ThreadPool::Submit<cpr::Session::GetAsync()::<lambda()> >(cpr::Session::GetAsync()::<lambda()>&&)::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `_M_create<cpr::ThreadPool::Submit<cpr::Session::DeleteAsync()::<lambda()> >(cpr::Session::DeleteAsync()::<lambda()>&&)::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `_M_create<cpr::ThreadPool::Submit<cpr::Session::DownloadAsync(const cpr::WriteCallback&)::<lambda()> >(cpr::Session::DownloadAsync(const cpr::WriteCallback&)::<lambda()>&&)::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `_M_create<cpr::ThreadPool::Submit<cpr::Session::DownloadAsync(std::ofstream&)::<lambda()> >(cpr::Session::DownloadAsync(std::ofstream&)::<lambda()>&&)::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `_M_create<cpr::ThreadPool::Submit<cpr::Session::HeadAsync()::<lambda()> >(cpr::Session::HeadAsync()::<lambda()>&&)::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj):C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161: more undefined references to `operator new(unsigned long long)' follow
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::to_string(long long)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:4068: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(unsigned long long, char, std::allocator const&)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:4069: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator[](unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_set_delayed_result(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>, std::weak_ptrstd::__future_base::_State_baseV2)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/future:430: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&&)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:3541: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::insert(unsigned long long, char const*)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:618: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::reserve(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:619: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::append(char const*, unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_countcpr::CurlHolder*(cpr::CurlHolder*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:917: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > >::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocatorcpr::Parameter::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocator<std::shared_ptrcpr::Interceptor>::allocate(unsigned long long, void const)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocator<curl_forms>::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(session.cpp.obj):C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: more undefined references to `operator new(unsigned long long)' follow
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(threadpool.cpp.obj): in function `time':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/time.h:256: undefined reference to `__imp__time64'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(threadpool.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::ThreadPool::CreateThread()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/threadpool.cpp:108: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(threadpool.cpp.obj): in function `thread<cpr::ThreadPool::CreateThread()::<lambda()> >':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_thread.h:142: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(threadpool.cpp.obj): in function `std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_countstd::thread*(std::thread*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:917: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(threadpool.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocator<std::_List_nodecpr::ThreadPool::ThreadData >::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::parseHeader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:71: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::substr(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:74: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_last_not_of(char const*, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:74: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::resize(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:81: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:84: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:87: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::erase(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:96: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find(char, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:98: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::substr(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:99: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:99: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::erase(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::find_last_not_of(char const*, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::resize(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:101: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::substr(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) const'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::headerUserFunction(char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, cpr::HeaderCallback const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:128: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long long, std::allocator const&)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::writeFunction(char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:133: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::append(char const, unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::writeFileFunction(char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits >)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:139: undefined reference to `std::ostream::write(char const, long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::writeUserFunction(char*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, cpr::WriteCallback const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:145: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long long, std::allocator const&)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::util::debugUserFunction(void*, curl_infotype, char*, unsigned long long, cpr::DebugCallback const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/util.cpp:157: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long long, std::allocator const&)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `__gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned long, char, int>(unsigned long ()(char const, char**, int), char const*, char const*, unsigned long long*, int)::_Save_errno::_Save_errno()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:63: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:63: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `__gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned long, char, int>(unsigned long ()(char const, char**, int), char const*, char const*, unsigned long long*, int)::_Save_errno::~_Save_errno()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:64: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:64: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(util.cpp.obj): in function `unsigned long __gnu_cxx::__stoa<unsigned long, unsigned long, char, int>(unsigned long ()(char const, char**, int), char const*, char const*, unsigned long long*, int)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:84: undefined reference to `__imp__errno'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(response.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::Response::Response(std::shared_ptrcpr::CurlHolder, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&&, cpr::Cookies&&, cpr::Error&&)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/response.cpp:7: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/response.cpp:8: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(response.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::Response::GetCertInfos()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/response.cpp:28: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/response.cpp:29: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(response.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocatorcpr::CertInfo::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(accept_encoding.cpp.obj): in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >&&)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:3531: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::insert(unsigned long long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(async.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::GlobalThreadPool::GetInstance()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/async.cpp:6: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(cookies.cpp.obj): in function `gmtime_s':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/time.h:264: undefined reference to `__imp__gmtime64_s'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(cookies.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocatorcpr::Cookie::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(curl_container.cpp.obj): in function `std::__new_allocatorcpr::Pair::allocate(unsigned long long, void const*)':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/new_allocator.h:137: undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long long)'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(curlholder.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::CurlHolder::CurlHolder()':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/curlholder.cpp:18: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(curlholder.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::CurlHolder::urlEncode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) const':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/curlholder.cpp:28: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: C:/msys64/vcpkg/installed/x64-mingw-dynamic/debug/lib/libcpr.a(curlholder.cpp.obj): in function `cpr::CurlHolder::urlDecode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&) const':
[build] C:\msys64\vcpkg\buildtrees\cpr\x64-mingw-dynamic-dbg/C:/msys64/vcpkg/buildtrees/cpr/src/0ce00c60cd-ac486fb55d.clean/cpr/curlholder.cpp:39: undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Scrapy.dir/build.make:103: Scrapy.exe] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Scrapy.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/Scrapy.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Makefile:154: Scrapy] Error 2
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/mehdi/OneDrive/Documents/1.0/C++/Scrap/build --config Debug --target Scrapy -j 10 -- exited with code: 2 and signal: null
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

OS : windows 8 64x
compiler : mingw
IDE : vscodium

I've tried to use it the same way on ubuntu and it works fine

Comment: You seem to be mixing the vcpkg manifest mode with the preinstalled-with-vcpkg package. First, I would suggest making up your mind on which you want. https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration.html  https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/examples/installing-and-using-packages.html

Comment: And then there's the cpr documentation on the matter: https://github.com/libcpr/cpr#cmake What you're showing follows none of these.